# How to trim middle section of query strings?

Tags: php, string, url

I want to modify some $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : "http://domain.com/blog/topics/post-name/uploads/flashfile.swf"

I want this output:        "http://domain.com/uploads/flashfile.swf"
```

So, the middle section "blog/topics/post-name/" need to be trimed. The actual words can change depends on which page the query_string is processed, especially the post-name is unpredicable.
How can I trim this middle section?

**Edit: the flashfile.swf is just an example, it can be different names with different extention.**

Comment: How is this releated to flex?  Where do you want to trim it? In flex or php?

Comment: sorry for the confusing, the querry string will be used by flex objects. The codes is in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is,

```
$url = "http://domain.com/blog/topics/post-name/uploads/flashfile.swf";
$str = str_replace($url, 'blog/topics/post-name/', '');
```

Here is a dynamic one.

```
$p = parse_url($url);
$v = basename($url);
$d = basename(dirname($url));
$str = $p['scheme']."://". $p['host']."/$d/$v";
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parsed = parse_url( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] );
$trimed = $parsed[ 'scheme' ] . '://' . $parsed[ 'host' ] . '/uploads/flashfile.swf';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
$url = "http://domain.com/blog/topics/post-name/uploads/flashfile.swf";
$new_url = str_replace($url, 'blog/topics/post-name/', '');
```